# pam_tally2 working is not as expected?

Tags: linux, ssh, security

I have been using pam_tally2 to lock a user after certain number of failed attempts through ssh

In */etc/pam.d/common-auth*

```
auth required pam_tally2.so deny=3 unlock_time=600
```

In */etc/pam.d/common-account*

```
account required pam_tally2.so
```

I have to tried to login through ssh,3 failed attempts is working fine not sure whether it is because of this `deny=3` or `MAxAUthtries` in sshd_config.

Also `pam_tally2 -u test` is showing `0`.

Can u help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `pam_tally2` configuration you have is what is locking out your bad attempts.

`deny` will:

> Deny access if tally for this user exceeds n.

From the documentation `MaxAuthTries` only locks out connections.

> Specifies the maximum number of authentication attempts permitted per connection. Once the number of failures reaches half this value, additional failures are logged. The default is 6.

This would be circumvented by creating a ssh new connection.

I am not sure why `pam_tally2 -u blah` would show zero unless you've had a successful login and/or you've reached the reset time of ten minutes you have configured.

**References**

[sshd_config man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config)

[pam_tally2 man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_tally2.8.html)